# How to set the content of an XYSeries using a list without using the add() function?

Tags: list, arraylist, jfreechart

I want to plot a simple x,y curve using jfreechart using the following code :

```
package temp;

import java.awt.BasicStroke;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Font;
import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import java.util.List;
import org.jfree.chart.ChartFactory;
import org.jfree.chart.ChartPanel;
import org.jfree.chart.JFreeChart;
import org.jfree.chart.plot.PlotOrientation;
import org.jfree.chart.plot.XYPlot;
import org.jfree.chart.renderer.xy.StandardXYItemRenderer;
import org.jfree.data.xy.XYSeries;
import org.jfree.data.xy.XYSeriesCollection;

public class recorder extends JFrame {
    int number=0;

    public recorder(int number, List time, List values) {    
        this.number=number;
        XYSeries series = new XYSeries(String.valueOf(number));

        // The 4 following lines are slow
        int n_value=time.size();
        for (int i=0;i<n_value;i++){
            series.add((double)time.get(i),(double)values.get(i));
        }
        // and that I would like to replace them by a "simple" assignement

        XYSeriesCollection dataset = new XYSeriesCollection(series);
        JFreeChart chart = ChartFactory.createXYLineChart("value","t","y",dataset,PlotOrientation.VERTICAL,true,true,false); 
        XYPlot plot = chart.getXYPlot();
        StandardXYItemRenderer renderer = new StandardXYItemRenderer();
        renderer.setSeriesPaint(0, Color.BLACK);
        plot.setRenderer(renderer);
        plot.setBackgroundPaint(Color.white);
        plot.setRangeGridlinesVisible(false);
        plot.setDomainGridlinesVisible(false);

        ChartPanel chartPanel = new ChartPanel(chart);
        chartPanel.setPreferredSize(new java.awt.Dimension(600, 400));
        chartPanel.setBackground(Color.white);
        setContentPane(chartPanel);
        pack();    
        setTitle("recorder"+String.valueOf(number));
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }
}
```

Does anybody know a way to do this and to get rid of the loop and the step-by-step add() method ? Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Create a custom class that `extends AbstractXYDataset`, as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=user%3A230513%20%5Bjfreechart%5D%20extends%20AbstractXYDataset), and give it a constructor or public method that accepts a `java.util.List<E>`. Then, instead of iterating though the list redundantly, your implementations of `getX()` and `getY()` can simply return the required value.

Comment: Thank you very much. I am going to try that. I will let you know if it works.